# A Quick Preview feature when mouse hover over the Image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, jquery

I'm Begginer in ASP.net and new here So I hope I'm following the post guideline here

Let's Assume that I search a product catalog and the result it displayed a multiple products with a Icon , I want when I hover on it that it execute a code that bring multiple texts from database and show it as pop up or small yellow box like tooltip.

for optimization purpose I want that the code is executed when it hover over the link so it can only get info when I hover over the Icon

I get it that it require JQuery(that I know next to nothing off) and bind it on hover event which will fire ajax query and return the data but beside that I'm Clueless as I don't know how to do the actual process

How Should you do it ? Can please tell me the resource (Book/Tutorial) that made you know how to do similar thing .

Comment: you can look at asp.net ajaxcontrol toolkit  popup that may be useful  http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small tutorial on how to use [ajax with asp.net webservice](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/jquery-ajax-examples-by-calling-aspnet.html).

[jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

You should look for Ajax or jQuery Related tutorial For you case  you can use this tutorial also

[AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

[Ajax ModalPopUpExtender Example to edit the gridview row values in asp.net](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-show-modalpopup-to-edit-gridview.html)

[AJAX ModalPopupExtender](http://technico.qnownow.com/ajax-modalpopupextender/)

[Working with ModalPopupExtender in ASP.NET and Ajax - Lesson 09 | .net courses](http://mrbool.com/working-with-modalpopupextender-in-asp-net-and-ajax-lesson-09/24609)

few examples for you..